# why arcgis server export distorted image distortion

Tags: arcgis

arcgis server export distorted image, why, see below screen shot

Details at
https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/915/arcgis-server-image-distortion-at-small-scale

Distorted sample 1:

https://transparentgov.net/earth/gps/googlemaps2/nav.html?centerlat=54.35775431752982&centerlong=15.991158175845065&centerzoom=4&currentlat=33.9345408&currentlong=-117.5977984&currentzoom=16&overlay=mgrs_image

[image]
[image]

Distorted sample 2:
https://transparentgov.net:3200/googlemaps110/default?layer_id=0&layer=Grid_Zone_Designation&center_lat=53.027993780816665&center_long=19.59959838750001&center_zoom=4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgis.la-quinta.org%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2Fcoordinate_systems%2Fmgrs%2FMapServer&overlayType=overlayType_image&panto=0

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are facing any bug with an existing software, please contact the maintainers of that software. If you have written that software on your own and face problems, please share more details, like the code involved that could help others to reproduce the problem

Comment: ESRI software have bug, obviously. They have not fix it since 20 years. You have to fix it by  youself. But I don't know how to fix it.